# Dojo Reading file through xhrGet

Tags: ajax, file, dojo, local

I am trying to run an xhrGet like this one:

```
dojo.provide("test"); 

dojo.declare("test",null,{ 

getVersion: function(){ 
details = 
{ 
    url: "../version.txt", 

    content: "test", 

    handleAs: "text", 

    timeout: 4000, 

    load: function(data) 
    { 
            console.log("result" + data); 
    }, 

    error: function(error) 
    { 
            console.log("Error" + error); 
    } 
} 

var dfd = dojo.xhrGet(details); 
return dfd; 

});
```

and I am getting this error:

Error: Deferred Cancelled: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Dojo1.4.3/dojo/_base/_loader/bootstrap.js :: anonymous :: line 1351"  data: no] 
file:///C:/Dojo1.4.3/dojo/_base/_loader/bootstrap.js 
Line 0

The file I am trying to retrieve is relative to dojo, therefore is located under Dojo1.4.3/version.txt

Other note.... I am not running it on a server, I am simply loading the html file with reference to the dojo class I have created.

thank you all for your time

**EDIT**

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs

you need to enable this policy in Firefox

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do AJAX requests if your page is being served directly via `file://`, for security reasons or something like that. You will need to set up a HTTP server and serve your page via that.

Also, is there any particular reason why you are using an old version of Dojo here? The current version is 1.7

Comment: I want to develop with the older version - I thought that you could load files with AJAX, is that a security enforcement ?

Comment: Sorry  but I found a way to do it, which means it is possible to do it and that you were... wrong, Firstly, you just need to follow these steps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs

Comment: This kind of thing is not necessarily cross browser. IT still easier to just use an HTTP server (if you have python installed you just need to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and you are done)

Comment: @missingno is right.  You can workaround the security, but you'll have to worry about this on other browsers and for others who use your app.

Comment: Hi Guys, yes, all of your suggestions are right, but I only need to develop it in FF, I don't want to use a server as I am doing simple unit testing.